# Opacity based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code, will make the "Go to top" button fade in when the scrollTop() is over 400px, that works fine, but i haven't found a way to make it fade out when i go back to the top.

```
$("#gototop").css("opacity", "0");
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $("#gototop").animate({
            opacity: 100,
        }, 3400);
    }
});
```

An **else** after the **if** didn't help, i tried different options with my non-ninja skills but none worked. Any ideas on how to make it fade out when the scroll is back at the top?

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using a plugin called [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) to handle the scroll position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a plugin called [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) to handle the scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of either an additional scroll handler that does the opposite or another if inside your first handler should do it (you want to test if `scrollTop() < 400`.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() < 400) {
        $("#gototop").animate({
            opacity: 0,
        }, 3400);
    }
});
```

Note though, that this is animating it on every call to the scroll event, you probably only want to do it once (when the scroll passes the 400px threshold) so maybe add a variable to record the current state of `#gototop`.

```
if(visible && $(this).scrollTop() < 400) {
    visible = !visible;
    //animate
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i've tried so far, both the aditional scroll handler and adding the if inside the same handler. I get either the #gototop button always there or not there at all. Don't know what else to try :(