# Adjust CSS Opacity With Element's Scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, opacity

Hi I want to bind the the CSS opacity of two divs with how much that element is scrolled.

For example say I have two divs:

```
<div class="red" style="background:red"></div>
<div class="blue" style="background:blue"></div>
```

As the red div comes into the viewport, its opacity goes from 0 to 100 - depending on the amount scrolled.

Likewise as the blue div comes into viewport its opacity goes from 100 to 0, depending on the amount scrolled.

I found this [Jquery/Javascript Opacity animation with scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702329/jquery-javascript-opacity-animation-with-scroll) -

```
    var fadeStart=100 // 100px scroll or less will equiv to 1 opacity
    ,fadeUntil=200 // 200px scroll or more will equiv to 0 opacity
    ,fading = $('#fading')
;

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop()
        ,opacity=0
    ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart ){
        opacity=1;
    }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
        opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
    }
    fading.css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
});
```

however the scroll amount is bound the document height, rather than the div itself.

Here is a jsfiddle to work from http://jsfiddle.net/RPmw9/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because offset = $(document).scrollTop() and not your element. I need to look into scrollTop property to see whether it is available to all elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on when you want it fully opaque or not, but this could be a start:

#### »»[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/wkAkQ/)«« (Multiple element class version - set individually)

#### »»[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/yrTpP/)«« (Single element class version - if only one element per class)

```
function fader() {
    var r = $('.red'),   // The .red DIV, as variable so we do not have to look
                         // it up multiple times.
        b = $('.blue'),  // Same for blue.
        wh = $(window).height(),      // Height of window (visible part).
        dt = $(document).scrollTop(), // Pixels document is scrolled down.
        /* red offset top is a semi static values which say how many pixels it
         * is from the top of the document.
         * "Red Offset Top" - "Document Scroll Top" gives us how many pixels
         * the red DIV is from top of visible window.
         * "Window Height" - that value gives us pixels the red DIV is from top
         * normalized to start from 0 when top of DIV is at bottom of window.
         * */
        redView  = wh - (r.offset().top - dt),
        // Same for blue DIV
        blueView = wh - (b.offset().top - dt),
        // Variable to save opacity value.
        op;
    /* If redView is bigger then 0 it means the DIV has top border above bottom
     * of window. 
     */
    if (redView > 0) {
        /* Opacity goes from 0 - 1 so we divide 1 by window height and
         * multiplies it with pixels red DIV is from bottom.
         * In addition we add the height of the red DIV to window height, such
         * that we set opacity until it is out of view (Bottom border is at top
         * of window, and not only until it has top border at top of window.)
         */
        op = 1 / (wh + r.height()) * redView;
        /* If value of calulation is less or equal to one, it is in visible
         * view and we set the opacity accordingly.
         */
        if (op <= 1)
            r.css('opacity', op);
    }
    if (blueView > 0) {
        op = 1 - 1 / (wh + b.height()) * blueView;
        if (op >= 0)
            b.css('opacity', op);
    }

    // Add this line for a possible help in understanding:
    console.log(
         'Window Height:', wh, 
         'Doc Scroll Top', dt, 
         'Red offset top:', r.offset().top, 
         'Red offs.top - Doc Scroll Top', r.offset().top - dt, 
         'View:', wh - (r.offset().top - dt)
    );
}
// Attach scroll event to the function fader()
$(document).bind('scroll', fader);
```

OK. Added some comments. Might not feel it is the best explanation. A better way to understand it is perhaps to have a look at the values so I also added a `console.log()` line inside the `fader()` function. Open your console and view the values as you scroll. [Fiddle with logging](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/ESdbs/). Also note this [performance difference](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-vs-style-direct). `style` is considerably faster.

#### Version two:

This set full opacity when element has top at top of window, (not bottom of element). Note that we could use the `Math.min()` in the above function as well, to omit the `op` variable and `if (op <= 1)` and `if (op >= 0)` statement, but not at least a quick benchmark on jsperf revealed the `if` version to perform slightly better. If you have many elements that you style one should use the `if` version.

#### »»[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/D9mMY/)««

```
function fader() {
    var r = $('.red'),
        b = $('.blue'),
        wh = $(window).height(),
        dt = $(document).scrollTop(),
        redView  = wh - (r.offset().top - dt),
        blueView = wh - (b.offset().top - dt);
    if (redView > 0) {
        // Math.min() returns the lowest of given values. Here we do not want
        // values above 1.
        $('.red').css('opacity', Math.min(1 / wh * redView, 1));
    }
    if (blueView > 0) {
        $('.blue').css('opacity', 1 - Math.min(1 / wh * blueView, 1));
    }
}
// Event on scroll
$(document).bind('scroll', fader);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is perfect! If you wouldn't mind could you explain the JavaScript a little so I can better understand how it works? Thanks so much though!!

Comment: @user3143218: OK. Added some comments. Not sure if it is understandable. Also added a line with `console.log()` which hopefully helps in understanding what is going on.

Comment: Thanks so much! Really comprehensive answer;) I had one issue, when I add multiple Blue and Red divs in the one page, it doesn't work properly. The console is error free tho :(

Comment: @user3143218: Yes, if you add multiple one way to go is to use unique ID's for each DIV instead of class. Else one could add a loop for the class as well. Here is an example looping all and setting individually: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/wkAkQ/)

Comment: @user3143218: Err. That was not good. I'll see if I get time to look at it.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: @user3143218: OK. Fixed and updated. Forgot to use `$(this).css` and used `r.css` and `b.css` .

Comment: Nice one! You're a champion.

Comment: Lastly, I noticed it a little laggy in Chrome. However I found that if you add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); to the colored elements, it forces hardware acceleration and is much faster.