# Use scroll bar as timeline for an animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to animate an element (an svg) just when you scroll, this far I triggered the animation while scrolling, but I want the scroll to act as a "timeline", so when you scroll the animation starts, but if you stop scrolling the animation pauses, and if you go up the animation goes backwards. I guess would be like a parallax scroll.

I know that there is plugins out there that solves the problem, but since I have time I was wondering if is posible to do it just with jquery.

So my question is: there is any way to do this just with plain jquery?

Comment: Of course there is. Question is too broad to provide more of an answer than that. Please come back when you have a specific code related problem

Comment: There are many jQuery plugins that have very nice solutions for what you're describing - which would be considered "plain jquery". Why recreate the wheel?

Comment: @charlietfl, a little harsh don't you think? Trifit is obviously new, and it's always better to support a new S.O. user than it is to turn them away because they ask a question not up to standard.

Comment: @stoves not at all... question does not fit within the site guidelines and is certainly `too broad` and is not code related

Comment: I would agree with @ElliotM ; Inspect jquery plugins that do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be along the same lines of what you're looking for:

[Jquery/Javascript Opacity animation with scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702329/jquery-javascript-opacity-animation-with-scroll)

The fiddle in the example uses scroll position to control opacity, I feel you largely could do the same for animation control:

http://jsfiddle.net/z7E9u/1/

```
var fadeStart=100 // 100px scroll or less will equiv to 1 opacity
    ,fadeUntil=200 // 200px scroll or more will equiv to 0 opacity
    ,fading = $('#fading')
;

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop()
        ,opacity=0
    ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart ){
        opacity=1;
    }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
        opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
    }
    fading.css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
});
```

Granted if you share some code with us we might be able to help you better. Right now you just have a vague question with an idea so all you will get are rough answers that about fit with your explained problem. Always good to SHOW code when asking questions if possible.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, yes it's true I had to show my code and specify more my question, I was in a rush (is not an excuse) and I know better, thanks. 

So basically, I'm triing to move a svg (a cloud) from one side of the screen to the other, controled by the scroll, so as long as you move down the scroll the cloud goes from right to left, but if you go up with the scroll the cloud goes back from left to right to the original position. this far I've been using this code:

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".cloud").animate({right:'110%'},5000);
    });

Comment: thanks for the code, as soon as I will arrive at home I will try it. 

I will also look for jquery plugins, although it is a self imposed exercice to learn more about jquery and I wanted to do it by myself