# Issues adding fadeIn to my navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a fadeIn to my navigation bar so when I get to a certain scroll point, the navigation bar fades in. However, my attempt is failing. I tried adding Jquery to regular javascript, so I am not sure if that is the issue or what the problem is. I am wanting the navigation bar to fadeIn only when it gets to the scroll point farther down the page where the navigation bar appears again.

This can be viewed at:

http://realtorcatch.com/test_index

My Javascript is:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
if (scrollTop >= document.getElementById("d").offsetTop) {
  document.getElementById("header").style.position = "fixed";
  document.getElementById("d").style.marginTop = "50px";
  document.getElementById("header").style.top = "0";
} else {
  $(function() { // $(document).ready shorthand
    $('#header').fadeIn('slow');
  });
document.getElementById("header").style.position = "static";
    document.getElementById("d").style.marginTop = "0px";
    document.getElementById("header").style.marginTop = "0px";
  }
}
```

Then I have the following div with all of my code in it:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, hide the header with `.hide()`, then the `.fadeIn()` call automatically removes the `display: none` when it fades the opacity to 100%.

```
$(function() { // $(document).ready shorthand
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;

      if (scrollTop >= document.getElementById("d").offsetTop) {
        if (!$('#header').hasClass('header-fixed')) {
          $('#header').addClass('header-fixed');
          $('#header').hide().fadeIn();
          document.getElementById("header").style.position = "fixed";
          document.getElementById("d").style.marginTop = "50px";
          document.getElementById("header").style.top = "0";
        }
      } else {
        document.getElementById("header").style.position = "static";
        document.getElementById("d").style.marginTop = "0px";
        document.getElementById("header").style.marginTop = "0px";
        $('#header').removeClass('header-fixed');
      }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/ogs9cem7/

Comment: Perfect. So what does adding the hasClass do? I see that basically you just had to put `.hide()` before the `fadeIn()`. I also see that I shouldn't have put it in the else area of it.

Is there anyway to make it fadeIn from the top? I am new to javascript, so please excuse my ignorance. Would this require the animate function?

Comment: @Paul basically the `.hasClass()` method checks if any of the selected elements have a specified class name. If any of the selected elements has the specified class name, this method will return "true", so it doesn't repeat the effect every time you scroll. You can make that effect using the css opacity property like in this samples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702329/jquery-javascript-opacity-animation-with-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Is Your Navigation Bar already hidden ?
Since the `fadeIn()` method gradually changes the opacity, for selected elements, `from hidden to visible` (fading effect).

If its not hidden than Please confirm weather you want to use `FadeIn` or `FadeOut`.

Comment: The navigation bar shows upon page load. Then when you scroll down the navigation bar appears once you get to the div of 'd'. I want it to fadeIn once it gets to the d div.

Comment: @Paul yes , thats what I am trying to say... to fade in ,, first your navigation bar should be hidden ..... than only fadeIn effect can be seen

Comment: I was first to answer and indicate where the problem was, but unfortunately no vote for me :(