# How can I make this background become less opaque as the page scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JQuery literally all I can do is make a div fade in and out if something is clicked and the JQuery you're about to see below. Anyways I was just wondering if someone could help me make this background less opaque as the screen scrolls down. So far I've managed to make it so that when the screen is 50px or more down then the background appears but I would like to be able to make it slowly become less opaque (slowly appear). Thanks for your help! :P

People are saying there's a question the same as mine, it's similar but not the same here's why:

I need the css selector "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)" the last value needs to slowly increase and make it's way to 1 (Example here: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1" ) as the page scrolls down. **THIS IS NOTHNG TO DO WITH OPACITY**

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 100) {
    $(".top-nav-container").css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1"});
  } else {
    $(".top-nav-container").css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0"});
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery/Javascript Opacity animation with scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702329/jquery-javascript-opacity-animation-with-scroll)

Comment: Read my code it's different maybe the same question almost but the Jquery code is completely different.

Comment: But it should give you an idea on how to solve it

Comment: Sorry mate it doesn't. That person is using offsets and I don't want to use offsets because I've heard it makes your site un-responsive

Comment: Nobody uses offset there, but whatever

Comment: rgba: Red, Green, Blue, Alpha. You say the question has nothing to do with opacity, but you are changing the opacity for the background-color just not an entire element.

Comment: No lol I meant the css selector itself "Opacity" sorry to confuse you haha :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate opacity based on the quotient of the scroll top height and the window height:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

    var wh = $(window).height();
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    var thisOpacity = 1 - (y / wh);    

    $(".top-nav-container").css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, " + thisOpacity + ")"});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but I can't use opacity seeing as it will take forever to get the text above to not be affected is there any way I can just add multiple sof 0.01 to the last value in this css selector "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"?

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work, the last " doesn't have a partner if that makes sense :/

Answer (score 1):

you can use fade in method with delay time

```
 $(".top-nav-container").fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: I see where you're coming from but then my WHOLE div will disappear and reappear where as im just looking for the background to be affected :P