# toggle class with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Hello i want to target the opacity of divs when the user scrolls down and remove it when he scrolls up again.That's the code i got so far.It works but i don't understand why i have to loop through it again in the esle condition or is their a better way of doing it.Pls only javascript no jquery.thank's alot.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',visible);

function visible(){
    if(window.pageYOffset>2000){
        var x = document.getElementById('wrapper').querySelectorAll('.div');
        i = 0;
        for (var i = 0 ; x.length >i; i++) {
            x[i].style.opacity = "1";
            x[i].style.transition = " 1s ease 0s ";
        }
    }else{  
        var x = document.getElementById('wrapper').querySelectorAll('.div');
        i = 0;
        for (var i = 0 ; x.length >i; i++) {
            x[i].style.opacity = "0";
            x[i].style.transition = " 1s ease 0s ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a list of the element hence you need to iterate

Comment: Because you have a collection of html elements, each time you need to set their opacity, you have to set for all of them...

Comment: simply create an high scope array with Elements starting with given id or class and then iterate over this array checking for your style. If exist remove it, if not add it. That's toggle the class...

Answer (score 1):

You should better set a class on your `#wrapper` and do the transition inside your CSS:

```
document
  .querySelector('#wrapper')
  .classList.toggle('-isVisible', window.pageYOffset > 2000);
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper .div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
#wrapper.-isVisible .div {
   opacity: 1;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',visible);

function visible(){
    var op;
    // decide what opacity will be
    if(window.pageYOffset>2000)
        op = "1";
    else
        op = "0";

    // then loop
    var x = document.getElementById('wrapper').querySelectorAll('.div');
    for (var i = 0 ; x.length >i; i++) {
        x[i].style.opacity = op; // use op here
        x[i].style.transition = " 1s ease 0s ";
    }
}
```

You can even make the code shorter by using a ternary operator and `forEach` like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',visible);

function visible(){
    var op = window.pageYOffset > 2000? "1": "0";

    // make the selector shorter too
    querySelectorAll('#wrapper .div').forEach(function(x){
        x.style.opacity = op;
        x.style.transition = " 1s ease 0s ";
    });
}
```

Comment: @JOESIG  You're welcome! Just want to say that cyrix's answer is much better. Check it out. Using a combo of JS and CSS is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right you shouldn't have to loop it twice as thats a lot of duplicated code. The only difference is whether opacity is set to 1 or 0 depending on the scroll position, so you can move that check inside the loop:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',visible);

function visible(){
    var x = document.getElementById('wrapper').querySelectorAll('.div');
    i = 0;
    for (var i = 0 ; x.length >i; i++) {
        x[i].style.opacity = window.pageYOffset>2000 ? 1 : 0;
        x[i].style.transition = " 1s ease 0s ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to loop over just use one class on parent and do the changes in the CSS

Comment: I know, but OP demonstrates a lack of understanding of conditionals in their question which this solution will better help to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might actually help:[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7E9u/2036/)

```
var fadeStart=100 // 100px scroll or less will equiv to 1 opacity
    ,fadeUntil=200 // 200px scroll or more will equiv to 0 opacity
    ,fading = $('#fading')
;

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop()
        ,opacity=0
    ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart ){
        opacity=1;
    }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
        opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
    }
    fading.css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
});
```

Here is the original question: [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702329/jquery-javascript-opacity-animation-with-scroll)